# Hide minted output completely without taking up space

Tags: floats, minted

Due to [issues](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/230) with Minted's `escapeinside` option, I would like to include, but completely hide (**without taking up any space**), a `minted` environment within my document. I do not want any of the content to be visible.

I've gotten pretty close with this hacky solution, which uses a tiny font size:

```
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\fontsize{0.01pt}{0.01pt}]{java}
public String someCode(String argument) {
    // code here...
}
\end{minted}
```

Is there a more elegant solution than just using a very small font size? Can I put it inside some sort of box, and set it to have a zero height? Can I float it somehow, such that it never gets actually shown anywhere in the document?

It's important that the code is actually processed. I therefore can't just comment it out, or use a `\if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a savebox with `\newsavebox`.

It's possible to then create an `lrbox` environment (specifying the savebox name), and throw the `minted` code listing inside a `minipage`.

```
\newsavebox\hideminted

\begin{lrbox}{\hideminted}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\fontsize{0.01pt}{0.01pt}]{java}
public String lookupUserNameByToken(String token) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from users where ";
    query += "token = '" + token + "'";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (rs.next()) {
        return rs.getString("name");
    }
    return null;
}
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
```

We then ensure that we never `\usebox{\hideminted}`, and it will never actually appear in the document.